# Filter a list of dictionaries by keys with different value for each key in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I will like to know if there a simpler way to filter a list of dictionaries by keys with different value for each key in Python
I wrote this code using a list for key values and a list for keys to search. It works.

Example:

```
Name = "A", Email = ".com" , Phone Number = "+1 (514"
```

Result =

```
{'Name': 'Agueda Pines', 'Email': 'apines@geekpack.com', 'Phone Number': '+1 (514)206-7191', '': ''}
```

Code:

```
lst_dicts = [
{'Name':'Agueda Pines','Email':'apines@geekpack.com','Phone Number':'+1 (514)206-7191'},
{'Name':'Angie Holt','Email':'aholt@geekpack.com','Phone Number':'+1 (506)310-8876'},
{'Name':'Arlette Thurgood','Email':'athurgood@gsupptech.com','Phone Number':'+1 (204)507-4424'},
{'Name':'Aurea Luedtke','Email':'aluedtke@gsupptech.com', 'Phone Number': '+1 (306)548-8163'},
{'Name':'Christene Bousquet','Email':'cbousquet@gsupptech.com','Phone Number':'+1 (514)491-3645'},
{'Name':'Dagny Beecher','Email':'dbeecher@gsupptech.com','Phone Number':'+1 (418)870-5530'},
{'Name':'Daniel Jameson','Email':'djameson@4ti.ca','Phone Number':'+1 (647) 953-5588 ext:2555'},
{'Name':'Dominique Pinkley','Email':'dpinkley@geekpack.com','Phone Number':'+1 (403)276-5180'},
{'Name':'Evita Brunk','Email':'ebrunk@geekpack.com','Phone Number':'+1 (604)226-4880'}

]

def get_count_list_dic(self, lst_dicts, srch_txt=[], srch_Keys=[]):
        index = 0
        tmp = lst_dicts
        while index < len(srch_Keys):
                [x.append(k) for k in tmp if srch_txt[index].lower() in k[srch_Keys[index]].lower()]
                tmp = x[:]
                x.clear()
                index += 1
        return len(tmp)
```

Comment: If this code works as intended, it might be more appropriate to ask for feedback on [codereview.se].

Comment: One change you can make is use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. You can `zip(srch_Keys, srch_txt)` to iterate both lists in parallel.

Comment: Am still scratching my head over the example. If you could expand on that, and provide a more helpful example, would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary seems a nice way to organize your inputs. In addition, you can use `sum` with a generator expression utilising `all`:

```
def get_count_list_dic(lst_dicts, srch_dict):
    return sum(all(v in item[k] for k, v in srch_dict.items()) for item in lst_dicts)

d = {'Name': 'A', 'Email': '.com', 'Phone Number': '+1 (514'}

res = get_count_list_dic(lst_dicts, srch_dict=d)  # 1
```

The trick here is to note `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so you can sum a Boolean sequence to count the number of `True` elements.

An alternative, equally valid, method is to use `zip` with sequences of keys and values. I prefer `dict` since, depending on how you construct the dictionary, you have an implicit check that each key has a value attached.

Answer (score 0):

you need a function returning boolean for testing when a key is in the key set, after which you can use `filter`:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: '''does a key from my keys match an entry?''', 
                lst_dicts)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a function that tests those conditions:

```
def sf(d):
    return 'A' in d['Name'] and '.com' in d['Email'] and '514' in d['Phone Number']
```

Then you can either use `filter` or a list comprehension to filter your list:

```
 >>> [d for d in lst_dicts if sf(d)]
 [{'Name': 'Agueda Pines', 'Email': 'apines@geekpack.com', 'Phone Number': '+1 (514)206-7191'}]

 >>> filter(sf, lst_dicts)
 [{'Name': 'Agueda Pines', 'Email': 'apines@geekpack.com', 'Phone Number': '+1 (514)206-7191'}]
```